# How to assign two parameters to 1 option in linux

Tags: linux

Hi I have two things and want to set both of them to a parameter.

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false"
```

what should be the delimiter between these two? 
I tried ';' and ':', both of them don't work.
I have also tried like this:

```
[yany@dev4508 ~/puma] export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true"
[yany@dev4508 ~/puma] export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false"
[yany@dev4508 ~/puma] echo $_JAVA_OPTIONS
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false
```

but only the most recent option work.

Comment: Where is `$_JAVA_OPTIONS` used?

Comment: Try with a comma. There is no universal convention so this will depend entirely on the program which reads these options.

Comment: It is used for ipv6 only client.